# Listen on TCP and UDP simultaneously with NetworkComms component

Tags: sockets, xamarin, tcp, xamarin.android, networkcomms.net

I have an android app which we are building using NetworkComms great networking components. One problem I am finding though is that now I want to listen for UDP broadcasts as well as direct messages I am only seeing the TCP ones and not picking up of the UDP ones.

My server code (simplified)

```
EventLog.Debug(TAG, "Starting message receiver");
DataSerialisation.ConfigureSerialisation();

this.HostAddress = GetIpAddress();
NetworkComms.AppendGlobalIncomingPacketHandler<CameraInfo>("CameraInfo", RegisterCallback);
NetworkComms.AppendGlobalIncomingPacketHandler<UserCheckIn>("UserCheckIn", CheckInCallback);
NetworkComms.AppendGlobalIncomingPacketHandler<CameraImage>("CameraImage", ImageCallback);
NetworkComms.AppendGlobalIncomingPacketHandler<StateChange>("StateChange", StateCallback);

mLocalPort = 8088;
Connection.StartListening(ConnectionType.TCP, new System.Net.IPEndPoint(GetIpAddress(), 8088));

EventLog.Debug(TAG, "Server TCP socket initialised. {0} port: {1}", this.HostAddress.ToString(), mLocalPort);

//Start listening for incoming UDP data as well
Connection.StartListening(ConnectionType.UDP, new IPEndPoint(GetIpAddress(), 10000));
```

and my client is transmitting the CameraInfo object on UDP this every few seconds:

```
private void BroadcastObject(object message) {
    var objectTitle = message.GetType().Name;
    UDPConnection.SendObject(objectTitle, message, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, 10000));
}
```

Can anyone tell me why the UDP sent objects never arrive but the TCP ones do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you sending objects to the TCP listener? Does the TCP sent objects get received by a other device, such as a desktop program?

Comment: its between android phones and android tablets. I have a UDP listener and TCP listener as the server code shows and I am attempting to send by UDP  for some objects (broadcast status updates) and TCP with others. Only TCP come through